# Java Failure on JUnit Case Calling a Method from a Subclass

Tags: java, methods, junit, subclass

I have the constructor `Alieni` from the subclass `Alieni` of the class `Settore` that sets the name `ALIENI` from the `enum` `Nome` to a certain `Settore` (composed by the integers `coordinataX` and `coordinataY`).

The test I'm trying to make is to verify that after running the method `Alieni` to a `Settore(3,10)` when I run the method `getSettoreNome` on the same `Settore` it should return the name `ALIENI` but it returns `null`.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    public class Settore {
            private Nome settoreNome;
            private final int coordinataX;
            private final int coordinataY;

        public Settore (int coordinataX, int coordinataY){
            this.coordinataX=coordinataX;
            this.coordinataY=coordinataY;
        }
        public Nome getSettoreNome() {
            return settoreNome;
        }
        public void setSettoreNome(Nome settoreNome) {
            this.settoreNome = settoreNome;
        }

    }
public enum Nome {
SICURO, PERICOLOSO, SCIALUPPA, ALIENI, UMANI
}
public class Alieni extends Settore {

    public Alieni(int coordinataX, int coordinataY) {
        super(coordinataX, coordinataY);
        setSettoreNome(Nome.ALIENI);
    }
}
public class AlieniTest {

    @Test
    public void testAlieni() {
        Settore settore = new Settore(3,10);
        new Alieni(3,10);
        assertEquals(Nome.ALIENI, settore.getSettoreNome());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't assigning the new instance of `Alieni` anywhere. Presumably you'd meant to assign it to `settore`:

```
public class AlieniTest {

    @Test
    public void testAlieni() {
        Settore settore = new Alieni(3,10);
        assertEquals(Nome.ALIENI, settore.getSettoreNome());
    }
}
```